# 'beforeinstallprompt' event not called for the PWA created on a SPA

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a SPA say `https://www.example.com`. And one of the sub-pages `https://www.example.com/foo` can be added as a PWA. On navigating to `/foo` from the homepage, the manifest and service-worker get installed and registered correctly and the PWA can be installed from the A2HS native buttons too, but the event `beforeinstallprompt` isn't called on chrome. If the page `/foo` is refreshed then the event is called. It's only when the navigation happens to it from another page that isn't in the scope of the PWA. The lighthouse audit passes all tests on `/foo` as well.
Has anyone tried creating multiple PWAs on a SPA, or encountered a similar issue?

Comment: I'm having this same issue using Gatsby.js - did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I'd retried recently and it worked well, maybe something got fixed in the chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a *good* solution, but this is how I got around it on my Gatsby.js site:

1. On *every* page (even those where I don't have the "Add to Homepage" custom trigger), I listen for the `beforeinstallprompt` event.
2. I set up a listener for a custom event on the `<html>` element on the pages that have my "Add to Homepage" custom trigger.
3. When `beforeinstallprompt` fires, I stash a reference to the event on the `<html>` tag (this does not get swapped out in between pages for my SPA) using jQuery's `$.data()` - I couldn't get vanilla JavaScript `dataset` to work but I may have been using it wrong, and I had jQuery loaded in anyway.
4. In the `beforeinstallprompt` handler, after setting the data, I fire the custom event on the `<html>` element.
5. The page that has the "Add to Homepage" custom trigger catches this custom event, grabs the reference to the `beforeinstallprompt` event from the `$( 'html ').data( 'event' )` and carries on with it as normal.

Hopefully that helps; it feels pretty hacky but I'm pretty new to PWAs / SPAs / React!